# Import data from old HDD (on a PC) to new MacBook

Tags: macos, hard-drive, migration-assistant

I'm planning to buy a new MacBook Pro for school next month, and I wanted to know if I can use Migration Assistant or any other tool to get all data from my old hard drive to the new one.

The problem is: My old MacBook doesn't work anymore and its not worth repairing it or something like that.

I took the HDD out of the notebook, and I can access it on my PC.

The OS version it contains is Lion (probably 10.7.2).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access your hard drive like any external hard drive with a kit that can turn it into an external. Like $30 at best buy. After accessing said drive take the information that you need off of it and then you can either keep it as a back up for those files or reformat it and use it as an external hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

To use Migration Assistant, make sure your PC and Mac are on the same Wi-Fi network or, for faster transfers, connect them with an Ethernet cable.

Then, on the PC, download and install the [Windows Migration Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1557).

Run that app on your PC and Migration Assistant on your Mac.

Follow the prompts on both computers to transfer your data; for complete details and step-by-step instructions, see [About Windows Migration Assistant on Apple’s website](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4796).

Comment: He does not have a Mac, just a hard drive **from** a Mac. However if you put the HD in an external case you can use Migration assistant on your new Mac to transfer files, settings and apps.

Comment: @SteveChambers QUOTE: I'm planning to buy a new MacBook Pro EOQ.

Comment: hence the part, "on your new Mac to transfer..."